# React router <Link> tag not working in my component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url-routing

I'm trying to build an app using React Router for routing. In the nav bar component, I add Link tags that will lead to another component all works fine but the data component. it renders a blank page when it is clicked on, Here's my code:

Navbar.jsx

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import './Navbar.css'
import { Outlet, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Fragment } from 'react';


class Navbar extends Component {
  
      render() {
        return(
                <Fragment>
                <div className='nav'>
                   < Link className='home-link' to='/'>
                      <h1 className='logo'> Energy Data Bank for Nigeria</h1> 
                    </Link>
                   <div className="nav-links">
                       
                         <Link className='about-link' to='about'>
                            About us
                        </Link>
                           <Link className='training-link' to='training'>
                                Training
                           </Link>
                          
                       <Link className='data-link' to='data'>
                           Data
                        </Link>
                        <Link className='signup' to='signUp'>Sign up</Link>
                       <Link className='login' to='logIn'>Login</Link>  
                   </div>
                   </div>
                   <Outlet />
         
                </Fragment>   
           )}
}

export default Navbar;
```

```
//data.jsx

import './Data.css'

export const Data = () => {

    return (
    <>
    <div className='data-section'>   
        <Link className="data-li" to='/electricity'>
            Electricity
            </Link>
        <Link className="data-li" to='/petroleum'>
            Petroleum
            </Link>
        <Link className="data-li" to='/gas'>
            Gas
            </Link> 
        </div>    
    </>
       
)}
```

I've tried replacing <Link> to  and it worked just fine

Comment: There is probably an error in the console

Comment: You should show your router configuration

Comment: i think you forgot the backslash, "/data"

 <Link className='data-link' to='/data'>